How to get all the templates by Powershell in sitecore
I need help to Pull a list of all templates within Sitecore including

Template Name
Number of pages using this template
URL of page using the template


Here's how to find all Sitecore templates and see how many pages use them, plus get their web addresses. We'll use PowerShell with some special Sitecore tools to do this.
# Fetch all templates from the path
$templates = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/templates/Project/Demo Sites" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "Template" }

# Prepare a result list
$results = @()

# Loop through each template and get related items
foreach ($template in $templates) {
    # Find all items using the current template
    $itemsUsingTemplate = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/content/Demo Sites/New site" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -eq $template.ID }

    # Get the number of items using the template
    $itemCount = $itemsUsingTemplate.Count

    # Prepare a list of URLs for items using this template
    $itemUrls = @()
    foreach ($item in $itemsUsingTemplate) {
        $url =  [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetItemUrl($item)
        $itemUrls += $url
    }

    # Add the template details to the result list
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Template Name" = $template.Name
        "Number of Pages Using Template" = $itemCount
        "Page URLs" = $itemUrls -join ", "
    }
}

# Output the result list
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

Hope It will work!!

To get a list of all templates in Sitecore along with the number of pages using each template and their URLs, you can use PowerShell with the Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE) module. Here Below I'm adding a script that should help you accomplish this task:
# Load Sitecore PowerShell Extensions
Import-Module "Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions"

# Define the path to the templates folder
$templatePath = "master:/sitecore/templates"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$results = @()

# Get all templates
$templates = Get-ChildItem -Path $templatePath -Recurse -Language "en" -Template "Template"

foreach ($template in $templates) {
    # Initialize counters
    $pageCount = 0
    $pageUrls = @()

    # Find items that use this template
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/content" -Recurse -Language "en" | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -eq $template.ID }

    foreach ($item in $items) {
        $pageCount++
        $pageUrls += $item.Paths.FullPath
    }

    # Create an object to store the result
    $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        TemplateName = $template.DisplayName
        NumberOfPages = $pageCount
        PageUrls = $pageUrls -join ", "
    }

    # Add the result to the results array
    $results += $result
}

# Output the results
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

Hope this help!!

Here is a very simple script you can use to get all the details you need.
Note: To reduce the result I am getting the templates of a specific path that is my site templates only, but you can change it accordingly. Also I am targeting the items of my single site.
# Fetch all templates from the path
$templates = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/templates/Project/Demo Sites" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "Template" }

# Prepare a result list
$results = @()

# Loop through each template and get related items
foreach ($template in $templates) {
    # Find all items using the current template
    $itemsUsingTemplate = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:/sitecore/content/Demo Sites/New site" -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateID -eq $template.ID }

    # Get the number of items using the template
    $itemCount = $itemsUsingTemplate.Count

    # Prepare a list of URLs for items using this template
    $itemUrls = @()
    foreach ($item in $itemsUsingTemplate) {
        $url =  [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetItemUrl($item)
        $itemUrls += $url
    }

    # Add the template details to the result list
    $results += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        "Template Name" = $template.Name
        "Number of Pages Using Template" = $itemCount
        "Page URLs" = $itemUrls -join ", "
    }
}

# Output the result list
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

When I run this, I get the following result.

Hope this helps.

You can use below Powershell snippet to get the details on the templates along with the number of items created from that template with the item url.
function Get-ItemUrl {
    param(
        [item]$Item,
        [Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext]$SiteContext
    )
    
    $result = New-UsingBlock(New-Object Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher $siteContext) {
        New-UsingBlock(New-Object Sitecore.Data.DatabaseSwitcher $item.Database) {
            [Sitecore.Links.LinkManager]::GetItemUrl($item)
        }
    }
    
    $result[0][0]
}

function Get-TemplateDetails{
    param(
        [string]$templatePath
    )
    
    $item = Get-ChildItem -Path "master:$templatePath" -Recurse
    $templates = $item | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -eq "Template"}

    $siteContext = [Sitecore.Sites.SiteContext]::GetSite("website")
    $output = @()
    $templates | ForEach-Object {
        $templateName = $_.Name
        $criteria = @(
            @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_templatename"; Value = $templateName; },
            @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = "/sitecore/content" } 
        )
        $props = @{
            Index = "sitecore_master_index"
            Criteria = $criteria
        }

        $templateItems = Find-Item @props
        
        $templateObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
        $templateObj | Add-Member -Name 'TemplateName' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $templateName
        $templateObj | Add-Member -Name 'NumberofItemsCount' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $templateItems.length
        
        if($templateItems -ne $null -and $templateItems.length -gt 0){
            $templateItemsObjects = @()
            $templateItems | ForEach-Object {
                $templateItem = Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $_.ItemId
                $itemUrl = Get-ItemUrl -SiteContext $siteContext -Item $templateItem
                $itemObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
                $itemObj | Add-Member -Name 'ItemUrl' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $itemUrl
                $templateItemsObjects += $itemObj
            }
            $templateObj | Add-Member -Name 'Items' -MemberType Noteproperty -Value $templateItemsObjects
        }
        
        $output += $templateObj
    }
    $output
}


$templateDetails = Get-TemplateDetails -templatePath "/sitecore/templates/User Defined"
Write-Host ($templateDetails | Format-List | Out-String)

In the above function Get-TemplateDetails is called to fetch all the template details along with the items derived from that template. It used Find-Item function in powershell to get all the items from the index derived from the particular template.
Below is the output from above powershell snippet containing template name, number of items with that template along with the item url.

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you have any queries.

To get a list of all templates in Sitecore, along with the number of pages using each template and the URLs of those pages, you can use below Sitecore PowerShell  Script:
# Get all templates in the Sitecore content tree
$templates = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/templates/*" -Language * -Recurse

$templateData = @()

foreach ($template in $templates) {
    # Get all items that use this template
    $itemsUsingTemplate = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content//*" -Query ".//*[@@templateid='$($template.ID)']"

    foreach ($item in $itemsUsingTemplate) {
        # Store template name, number of pages, and URLs
        $templateData += [pscustomobject]@{
            TemplateName = $template.DisplayName
            PagesUsingTemplate = $itemsUsingTemplate.Count
            PageURL = $item.OuterItem.Paths.FullPath.Replace("master:/sitecore/content", "https://www.yourwebsite.com")
        }
    }
}

$templateData | Format-Table -AutoSize


Hope this helps you!
